# BeagleBone Black eMMC API

Tags: beagleboneblack

I have been looking though StarterWare and would like to write code that will be using the on board 2GB eMMC. I was looking though the documentation (TRM & the BBB SRM) and found that it is connected to MMC1. I understand this much so far.

My question is, I know there is an API for accessing the SD card in StarterWare, is there also one for the the eMMC. By any chance is it the api in the folder labeled "nandlib"?

Comment: As it turns out, there is no "out of box" support in starterware to do this. After asking on ti E2E, there is a way but only after manipulating a api to work for this use. They also basically said it was on their to-do list. I'll try and update this question with a well informed answer once I get more information.

Comment: Would love to hear what you've learned on this. I need to flash SD to eMMC and be able to boot from it. Linux does it, so why can't we?

Comment: I have not followed up on this anymore. Here is the link to where I asked the question on TI E2E https://e2e.ti.com/support/embedded/starterware/f/790/t/452128.  This is a suggested API that has implemented eMMC access. https://sourceforge.net/projects/starterwarefree/?source=directory